# How to modify lines in Python stream

Tags: python, text, stream

I am using psycopg2 to export a PostgreSQL table.

```py
file = sys.stdout # writable file
cur.copy_to(file, "example_table")
```

I have a transformation that I would like to apply to each line of the file as it is exported.

```py
def transform(line):
  # ...
  return line
```

How should I do this?

I could implement my own TextIO class from scratch, but it seems like there ought to be a simple, less error-prone way to modify this output line by line.

Comment: have you tried the Stream module here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-stream.html